# How to host user-generated HTML pages from Java web app?

Tags: java, html, spring

My Java web application needs to serve up many static HTML reports.

The reports are generated on-demand using a 3rd party application based on user's inputs. The reports will always be different from run to run, so they can't be cached. The reports **include multiple HTML pages** (including JS and CSS pages), and relative links between files.

What's the easiest way to serve up these reports to the front-end user?

The reports don't need to stick around -- they can be deleted after a set time or after the user logs out.

I'm using:

- Tomcat 7
- Spring framework

Here is a similar **example**:

Suppose the web app is an online IDE, and you'd like to occasionally generate and display Javadoc pages for the project.

Comment: i think try to copy your static resource into apache2 it should work for you

Comment: this is far too broad, and not clear

Comment: @NimChimpsky What's not clear? The Java web app received some arbitrary static HTML files. How can it serve them up to the front-end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally use a web server, such as Apache, to do this, since my Java applications are always behind Apache. Here is an Apache example:

```
# Serve /path/to/html/files/ with static files stored at /var/path/to/files/
ProxyPass /path/to/html/files/ !
Alias /path/to/html/files/ /var/path/to/files/

# Proxy / to Java application at localhost:8080
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

If you must use a pure Java solution, you could try to set up a file download servlet, [such as this one by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2007/07/fileservlet.html). Just be careful about handling file paths supplied in request urls, as the servlet can be vulnerable to [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).